# Asynctask not executing while running but executing in debugging

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Am executing two AsyncTask in an sequence manner. While debugging its working fine. But while running the app, second AysncTask not executing. Tried with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR not helping.below is my code.I don't have any idea about this problem.Below is my complete code.While running headerList.size() tgrowing zero. If the AsyncTask executed correctly, the size will be 2.

```
public class MainmenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
        networkCheck(context,rl);

    }

    private void loadPage(){
       // new GetMenu().execute();
        GetMenu getMenuTask = new GetMenu();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getMenuTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            getMenuTask.execute();
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        System.out.println("List Size "+ headerList.size());
        for(int i=0;i<headerList.size();i++)
        {
            String title = headerList.get(i).getMenuName().toString();
            GlobalClass.menuId = headerList.get(i).getLangID().toString();
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), title);
            menu.add(title);
            //viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void networkCheck(Context context,LinearLayout rl) {

        boolean isConnected = NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(context);

        if (isConnected) {
            if(GlobalClass.languagueSelection.toString().equals("")){
                LanguageSelectionDialog languagueDialog =new LanguageSelectionDialog(MainmenuActivity.this);
                languagueDialog.show();
            }else{
                loadPage();
            }
        } else {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(rl, "No Internet Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainmenuActivity.this, MainmenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

        }
    }

    private class GetMenu extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainmenuActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(menuURL);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from MenuURL: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray lanList = jsonObj.getJSONArray("menu");

                    for (int i = 0; i < lanList.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = lanList.getJSONObject(i);
                        String langID = jsonObject1.optString("id");
                        String menuID = jsonObject1.optString("menu");
                        headerList.add(new Language(langID,menuID));

                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainmenuActivity.this, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainmenuActivity.this,
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

    public class LanguageSelectionDialog extends Dialog {


        public LanguageSelectionDialog(Activity a) {
            super(a);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.languagueSelection = a;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.languague_selection_dialog);
            getLanguagues = new GetLanguagues();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                getLanguagues.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            } else {
                getLanguagues.execute();
            }            }

        private class GetLanguagues extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(languagueURL);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray lanList = jsonObj.getJSONArray("language");

                        for (int i = 0; i < lanList.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = lanList.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = jsonObject1.optString("id");
                            String langId = jsonObject1.optString("language");
                            dashBoardList.add(new LanguagueSelection(id,langId));
                            lanlist.add(langId);
                            GlobalClass.langId=id;

                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                spnLanguagueSelection.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lanlist));
                getLanguagues.cancel(true);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

StackTrace while Running:

```
12-28 07:13:05.294 17448-17468/com.appathon.siva.news E/ContentValues: Response from url: {"language":[{"id":"21","language":"Hindi"},{"id":"20","language":"English"},{"id":"19","language":"Tamil"}]}
12-28 07:13:10.175 17448-17448/com.appathon.siva.news I/Choreographer: Skipped 297 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-28 07:13:11.616 17448-17448/com.appathon.siva.news I/System.out: List Size 0
12-28 07:13:11.662 17448-17463/com.appathon.siva.news W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-28 07:13:11.662 17448-17463/com.appathon.siva.news W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3fcd200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-28 07:13:11.682 17448-17472/com.appathon.siva.news E/ContentValues: Response from MenuURL: {"menu":[{"id":"14","menu":"Latest News"},{"id":"13","menu":"Top News"}]}
```

StackTrace while Debugging

```
12-28 07:27:17.155 17557-17579/com.appathon.siva.news E/ContentValues: Response from url: {"language":[{"id":"21","language":"Hindi"},{"id":"20","language":"English"},{"id":"19","language":"Tamil"}]}
12-28 07:27:17.166 17557-17573/com.appathon.siva.news W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-28 07:27:17.166 17557-17573/com.appathon.siva.news W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe3873d40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-28 07:27:30.429 17557-17583/com.appathon.siva.news E/ContentValues: Response from MenuURL: {"menu":[{"id":"14","menu":"Latest News"},{"id":"13","menu":"Top News"}]}
12-28 07:27:33.836 17557-17557/com.appathon.siva.news I/System.out: List Size 2
```

List size is printing in different scenarios.

Comment: wait some times.

Comment: 2 AsyncTasks but here it's only one? GetMenu?? Can you post remaining code as well?

Comment: @Siva can u put some logs in doInBackground methods of those Asynctasks and check once?